# Activate Android app by pressing thumb on timeout / locked screen for few seconds

Tags: touchscreen

This might seem  like a strange question. Is there some sort of way for an  app to launched by pressing the screen for a few seconds on touch screen phones? the reason why I ask is because this would be a great feature for like a panic button. of course the app will have to calibrate to the owner's thumb to prevent accidental pressing from objects in purse or pockets.

Regards.

Comment: I would suggest instead asking the phone manufacturers to add an actual 'Panic' button to their device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't really possible. But there are apps available in the Play Store that implement a Panic Button where you can place a button on your home screen (and maybe also your lock screen, but I haven't it yet).

One of those apps I found is [Red Panic Button](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.ucsoftware.panicbuttonpro). But you can also have a look in the Play Store yourself if you search for something like [Panic Button](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Panic%20button&c=apps) etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are several [shutdown apps on the market](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=shut%20down&c=apps), they all needed root. You can combine them with WidgetLocker and put their icons on your lockscreen for quick shutdown.